# Django queryset order_by specify order

Tags: django

I have this Model :

```
class Project(models.Model):
    COLORS = (
        ('#FFFF00', "new project to analyse"),
        ('#FFFCCC', "to analyse"),
        ('#FFAFFF', "analysis in progress"),
        ('#FFFFFF', "project validated"),
        ('#008800', "project validated today"),
        ('#66B2FF', "project not validated"),
        ('#004DDD', "project not validated and deleted"),
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name="Project name", default="")
    color = models.CharField(max_length=7, choices=COLORS, null=True, blank=True)
```

and I want to get a queryset with all the projects sorted by color.
So i did this :

`projects = Project.objects.order_by('color')`

My problem is that the colors are sorted in alphabetical order, but I want them sorted in the order of 'COLORS' (first '#FFFF00', then '#FFFCCC' ...)

Answer (score 1):

You can work with a [*condition expression* <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#conditional-expressions):

```
from django.db.models import Case, IntegerField, Value, When

Project.objects.alias(
    color_order=Case(
        *[When(color=color, then=Value(i)) for i, color in enumerate(COLORS)],
        output_field=IntegerField()
    )
).order_by('color_order')
```